# Gradle does not detect change when using Copy task with expand

Tags: gradle

I'm gradle to copy files and replace strings in them using expand method.
The problem is when the values of expand are changed gradle still treat the destination files as up-to-date. I have to clean and build the files to get the correct values.

This is the copy task:

```
task copyProductionConfig(type: Copy) {
  from 'source'
  include 'config.properties'
  into 'build/war/WEB-INF/config'
  expand([
    databaseHostname: 'db.company.com',
    version: versionId,
    buildNumber: (int)(Math.random() * 1000),
    date: new Date()
  ])
}
```

Even when the version is changed gradle still see the result file as up-to-date.

Comment: Two questions. Why don't You use war plugin? Do You use *clean* task?

Answer (score 5):

That's indeed a pity. But it should be easily fixed by doing

```
task copyProductionConfig(type: Copy) {
  from 'source'
  include 'config.properties'
  into 'build/war/WEB-INF/config'
  def tokens = [
    databaseHostname: 'db.company.com',
    version: versionId,
    buildNumber: (int)(Math.random() * 1000),
    date: new Date()
  ]
  expand(tokens)
  inputs.properties(tokens)
}
```

That way, the tokens are added to the inputs of the task, and the task is thus re-executed if the tokens have changed since the last execution.